# Trouble understanding result in Simes (1986) $\Pr\{ P_{(j)} > \frac{j\alpha}{n} ; j = 1,...,n \} = 1-\alpha$

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, multiple-comparisons, order-statistics

I'm referencing this [paper](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Esteele/Courses/956/ResourceDetails/MultipleComparision/Simes86pdf.pdf).

On page 752, a theorem is presented which states that

If $P_{(1)},\cdots,P_{(n)}$ are the order statistics of $n$ independent random variables from a $\rm Unif(0,1)$ distribution, define $A_n(\alpha)$ as

$$A_n(\alpha) = \Pr\left\{ P_{(j)} > \frac{j\alpha}{n} ; j = 1,\cdots,n\right\}$$ for $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$

Then $A_n(\alpha) = 1 - \alpha.$

The result is proved using induction, but I'm having trouble understanding all of the pieces of this proof.

The base case (true for $n=1$) makes sense to me. I understand that $P_{(n)}$ has a cumulative distribution function of $p^n$.

I don't understand why $\{ P_{(1)}/P_{(n)},\ldots, P_{(n-1)}/P_{(n)} \}$ is useful or why this is a set of uniform random variables (the ratio of uniform random variables isn't uniform itself right?).

I also don't understand why we can say

$$A_n(\alpha) = \int\limits_{\alpha}^1 A_{n-1}\left(\frac{\alpha (n-1)}{pn}\right)np^{n-1} dp$$

Even the final step (if $A_{n-1}(\alpha) = 1-\alpha$ then so does $A_n(\alpha)$) seems kind of cryptic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to write some details to understand the proof. First,

$\{P_{(j)}>\frac{j\alpha}{n},j\in[1,n]\}=\{P_{(n)}>\alpha\}\cap\{\frac{P_{(j)}}{P_{(n)}}>\frac{j\alpha}{P_{(n)}n},j\in[1,n-1]\}$

Thus, $A_n(\alpha)=\mathbb{P}(\{P_{(n)}>\alpha\}\cap\{\frac{P_{(j)}}{P_{(n)}}>\frac{j\alpha}{P_{(n)}n},j\in[1,n-1]\})$

This can be rewritten as

$A_n(\alpha)=\mathbb{E}_{P_{(n)}}[\mathbb{1}_{\{P_{(n)}>\alpha\}}\mathbb{P}(\frac{P_{(j)}}{P_{(n)}}>\frac{j}{n-1}\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{P_{(n)}n},j\in[1,n-1])]$

Because, $(P_{(j)})_{j\in[1,n-1]}$ are the order statistics of n-1 independent uniform (0,1), it is the same for $(P_{(j)}/P_{(n)})_{j\in[1,n-1]}$. Indeed, if $(P_i)$ are uniform $(0,1)$, $(P_i/P_{(n)})$ are uniform $(0,1/P_{(n)})$, $P_{(n)}$ being uniform $(0,1)$. That is why

$\mathbb{P}(\frac{P_{(j)}}{P_{(n)}}>\frac{j}{n-1}\beta,j\in[1,n-1])=A_{n-1}(\beta)$

As a result,

$A_n(\alpha)=\mathbb{E}_{P_{(n)}}[\mathbb{1}_{\{P_{(n)}>\alpha\}}A_{n-1}(\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{P_{(n)}n})]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{\{x>\alpha\}}A_{n-1}(\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{x n})f_{P_{(n)}}(x)dx$

what leads to the integral.

Then $A_1(\alpha)=1-\alpha$. Using the expression of $A_n(\alpha)$, it is easy to see that $A_1(\alpha)=A_2(\alpha)$, etc.
Indeed, if $A_{n-1}(\alpha)=1-\alpha$, $A_n(\alpha)=[p^n]_{\alpha}^{1}-\alpha[p^{n-1}]_{\alpha}^1$